# The extensions for my MKMapAnnotation works 1/3 times, is there any way to fix it so that it works all of time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkannotation, mkannotationview

So I am making an app that requires the use of MKMapAnnotations in swift, in order to do this I used an extension that customizes each annotation to have a button, a custom image, and a background. All of this works on the first attempt, however, for the second and third attempts it shows the default annotation with no buttons or functionality to the annotations, but on the fourth attempt it works (and every third attempt after). To do this I am signing in and out of my app and reloading the MapView. What is the reason for this/ How do I solve this? Here is the extension.

This is my first time posting here so any advice pertaining to how to help you help me would be appreciated as well :)

```
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    // 1

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        // 2
        guard let annotation = annotation as? Artwork else { return nil }
        // 3
        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
        // 4

        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
            as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
            view.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "TiffinIcon")
            view.markerTintColor = UIColor.orange
        }
        else {
            // 5
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            view.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "TiffinIcon")
            view.markerTintColor = UIColor.orange
            //view.tag = counter
            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "TiffinIcon"), for: .normal)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            //view.tag = counter
            print("counter tagged:\(counter)")


        }
        return view
    }
    //Button Clicked Function
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if let annotation = view.annotation as? Artwork {
            print("This is the \(annotation.tag)")
            newTag = annotation.tag
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "successfulSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’d wager that it’s not related to this code, but perhaps, somehow, the second time you run it, the map view’s delegate is not set. I’d add some logging statement and/or breakpoint, and I wager it’s not getting to this routine at all. The other alternative is that the  annotation is not an `Artwork` the second time around. But I don’t think the above is enough to manifest the problem you describe. The problem likely rests elsewhere. Add some debugging messages and breakpoints to confirm.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked turns out the whole extension doesn't run, how do I make sure it runs every single time?

Comment: You likely have some path of execution where a map view is being created but it’s `delegate` is not getting set (or less likely, it’s getting reset to something else or `nil`). So, go back a step and set breakpoint where you set the delegate, and make sure you’re hitting that code, too. But, the take home is that there almost certainly is not any strange but in map view that prevents it from calling its delegate methods, but (with no offense intended) rather the problem certainly rests in how you’re using it.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the problem, I put the code in a viewDidAppear so it must have not run properly, fixed that and everything works.